# Java JSoup Parsing webpages via a Blocked IP

Tags: java, jsoup

I am connecting to a URL in JSOUP  say `www.ABC.com` . This website blocks the IP if you access it 3 times. Now is there any way to connect to this web page once it blocks my IP. I also tried using proxies.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "178.62.238.17");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "3128");
Document cityDoc = Jsoup.connect(cityURL)
                         .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
                         .get();
```

Still I get `HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403`

**PS : Jsoup.connect() works for me for 1st 3 time and then it throws above error since my IP is blocked**

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to connect to a website which locks you're IP after a few attempts, there is generally not a lot you can do about this. If you are crawling a certain page, maybe they have webservices which prodide you some of the data you are looking for volunteraly.

But the general answer is: no.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience or observation i found that when we hit more request to website .website identify our ip .after limit cross they block us just because of they know some fraud things happen with site.

For solution please use HMA for network or set proxy ip at request time .but remember on mind that ip recursively changed at request time.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make things slow, that is to put random long sleeps in between. Usually the website blocks you if too many attempts are made in a short period of time. Introducing the random long waits will trick the server to believe it is actually a person and not a bot. Of course this will cause your code to run much slower, but at least it will still be automatized.